Flutter pdf Uint8List to String
I have a Uint8List with the information of a pdf. I need to convert this information into String in order to save the pdf info to use it later. But, there is a problem with the proccess and the pdf info breaks. This is the saving code:
Future<void> setFormPdf(File pdf)async{
    final String pdfKey = _getKey('pdf_name');
    final bytesData = pdf.readAsBytesSync();
    final pdfData = utf8.decode(bytesData, allowMalformed: true);
    await storageConnector.setString(pdfData, pdfKey);
}

If i don't use the utf8.decode method with the parameter allowMalformed true, the app throws an exception about the utf8 encoding.
Later, when i'm going to recover the pdf info, i use the next code
final pdfPath = await getTemporaryPath('pdf_name.pdf');
final pdfData = File(pdfPath);
final String pdfKey = _getKey('pdf_name');
final stringPdf = await storageConnector.getString(pdfKey);
final bytesPdf = utf8.encode(stringPdf);
await pdfData.writeAsBytes(bytesPdf, flush: true);

So, what do i have to do? Do i have to use another method to convert Uint8List into String?

I found the solution. I just had to decode the Uint8List in to String with the method String.fromCharCodes(bytesData), and i had to encode the String information again with the method Uint8List.fromList(stringPdf.codeUnits).
